# Is a cursor the only way to do this?

Tags: php, mysql, cursor

I'm in the process of churning through some raw data that I have. The data are in a MySQL database. The data lists, in a millisecond-by-millisecond format, which of a number of possible 'events' are currently happening. It has only a few columns:

1. id - unique identifier for the row
2. event - indicates which event is currently occurring

What I would like to do is get some basic information regarding these data. Specifically, I'd like to create a table that has:

1. The id that an event starts
2. The id that an event ends
3. A new id indexing the events and their occurrence, as well as a column detailing which event is currently happening.

I know that this would be easy to deal with using PHP, just using a simple loop through all the records, but I'm trying to push the boundaries of my MySQL knowledge for a bit here (it may be dangerous, I know!!).

So, my question is this: would a cursor be the best thing to use for this? I ask because events can occur multiple times, so doing something like grouping by the event type won't work - or will it? I'm just wondering if there is a clever way of dealing with this I have missed, without needing to go through each row sequentially.

Thanks!

Comment: is the ID, by any chance, and auto increment column? I can think of maybe a left join to get the next record's start time and using all values for an insert in to the new table. Efficient? Maybe not, but effective. -- EDIT: the more I think about it, why the new table at all? A join could give you all the information you need while still retaining the current table and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To demonstrate what I commented earlier about, say you have the following table:

```
event_log
  id    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  start DATETIME
  event VARCHAR(255)                     # or whatever you want for datatype
```

Gathering this information is as simple as:

```
SELECT   el.*,
         (SELECT   el_j.start            # -
          FROM     event_log el_j        #  |
          WHERE    el_j.id > el.id       #  |- Grab next row based on the next ID
          LIMIT    1) as end             # -
FROM     event_log
ORDER BY start;
```

Comment: Thanks - very cunning! I've tried implementing it, but there is a slight problem - the id column is essentially an auto-increment column, which has been output by a different program, indexing time since the start of recording (starting at 1). The problem is that the table structure is this: " event_log
  id    INT  
  event VARCHAR(255)  ", and I was wondering in there was a method to work out what the start and end times (shown in id). In other words, it's a step behind the code that you have suggested!

Comment: @vize: So how would you determine time? If I can have that equation I can probably help you out. ;-) (There's `ADDTIME()` and `ADDDATE()` which you can couple with the ID to get the time offset)